# Cannot get events working in Sterling Trader samples

Tags: c#, .net, com, activex

I'm just trying to run the C# quotes sample from Sterling Trader; if I run it with Sterling Trader Pro open, it doesn't crash, but events never get called. I suspect that Sterling Trader Pro is swallowing those events somehow, since I remember that the API guide recommended avoiding running more than one instance of the API at a time.

But if I close Sterling Trader Pro and run the sample from VS2015, as soon as I create an object from the API, the program crashes saying "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID xxxxx  failed due to the following error: 80040154."

Why does it work with the Trader open and not when it's closed? The Api is an ActiveX control; the project has a COM reference to the Sterling Type Library. From my research, I tried changing the project's platform from "Any CPU" to "x86" to enforce 32 bits, but I get the same error.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad: The Sterling ActiveX Api is meant to communicate with an open instance of Sterling Trader Pro. It's the way it's meant to work.

On the other hand, I wasn't receiving the events because the account had not been activated yet (not my bad, the stakeholder's this time), and thus could not receive real time data.